# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType

Tags: java, spring, jackson, apache-camel

I am getting an error while accessing an endpoint in the local machine:

**Error Logs:**

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-aaayush-mac-1697010426104-0-3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1842)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:389)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.doService(CamelContinuationServlet.java:220)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:79)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
    at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:421)
    at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:199)
    at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:103)
    at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverters.read(ModelConverters.java:76)
    at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverters.read(ModelConverters.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestModelConverters.readClass(RestModelConverters.java:33)
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerReader.appendModels(RestSwaggerReader.java:755)
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerReader.parse(RestSwaggerReader.java:227)
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerReader.read(RestSwaggerReader.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerSupport.renderResourceListing(RestSwaggerSupport.java:224)
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerProcessor.process(RestSwaggerProcessor.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestApiProducer.process(RestApiProducer.java:36)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    ... 39 more
```

**Exception:**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
    <camel.version>2.25.4</camel.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.5</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the Jackson dependency for Camel that I am using in the project.

Comment: We'll need more information than that

Comment: @Jorn Added thanks

Comment: If you're getting a `NoSuchMethodError`, that most likely means you compiled with a different Jackson version from the one you have at runtime.

Comment: When you read a stack trace you should not consider the exception message only: the exception class gives a lot of context.  In this case the exception class is `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: @Jorn Any solution or proper dependency versions to resolve this issue

Comment: You are using an old version of Camel which uses Jackson 1.9.12, so trying to mixin a 2.12 version will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you run the command:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and get the version of artifacts containing this class: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember`

`NoSuchMethodException` always be raised because the dependencies jar
has multiple version, the direct dependency lib you are using depends on another lib, but there has multiple version in your pom, and the older version Class may not contain the method you are using.

Answer (score 1):

**camel-jackson-starter** version `2.25.4` uses `2.9.10.7` version of **jackson-databind**.

Please update your **pom.xml** by adding these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.10.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

See if this works.

Comment: @AayushSaini See this if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it causing some errors: logs:Error creating bean with name 'jaxbAnnotationIgnoreNillModule' defined in class path resource This bean is already defined in my config: Factory method 'jaxbAnnotationIgnoreNillModule' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector$XmlExtension

Comment: @AayushSaini I have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks, Getting error threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/json/JsonMapper

Comment: @AayushSaini Try by removing databind and jaxb-annotations dependencies and keep jsr dependency with version 2.9.10 and see if it works

Comment: Thanks Not working.]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn

Comment: @AayushSaini Can you provide your codebase via github? I can fix it quickly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255586/discussion-between-aayush-saini-and-anish-b).